# PhpMyAdmin change default insert rows value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When you try to insert a single row in a table using `PhpMyAdmin` it has a default number of rows to insert set to `2`, so everytime I have to change that value to 1, otherwise it throws a truncated error, and adds 2 rows (The second one being empty). How can I change this default value to `1` ?

Comment: In my phpMyAdmin, there is a checkbox labeled `Ignore` at the second insert, which is checked by default and turned off when you put a value in one of the inputs. Don't you have that checkbox? Do you use a recent version of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes I have seen the check, but is there a way to change the number by default? Sounds lazy but un-checking that everytime is not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the phpMyAdmin main page:

Settings > Main panel (or: Main frame) > Edit mode > Number of inserted rows

Change the value and hit Apply.

Tested with phpMyAdmin 3.4.11 and 4.2.10. See also [phpMyAdmin 4.2 documentation: `$cfg['InsertRows']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/QA_4_2/config.html#cfg_InsertRows).

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to change the number of rows that are displayed there (though I suppose you could open a feature request for that if you wish).

However, I'm completely unable to reproduce your trouble. As DanFromGermany says, the ignore checkbox is selected by default, so unless you actually un-check the checkbox manually or type in one of the fields for the second row, it's ignored. Your response to his comment doesn't make sense because you shouldn't be unchecking it (the label is "ignore" so un-checking it says "do not ignore" the second row); in fact you shouldn't need to do anything, the default action is to ignore that. Perhaps you could post a screenshot of your screen just before submission of the form? What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Answer (score -1):

From phpMyAdmi,Click the settings icon on the right top corner as shown in the screenshot
[image]

Then You will find a popup for changing settings like this
[image]

Change the number of inserted row to 1 then click APPLY to apply settings 
And that's the magic

Tested in **phpMyAdmin 4.5.1**